# Creating user with same UserName and Email always return invalid user name error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

Tried to create a user in identity tables using .net core. But it always return an error invalid UserName.

```
        var user = new ApplicationUser();
        user.UserName = "SuperAdmin1@gmail.com";
        user.Email = "SuperAdmin1@gmail.com";

        string userPWD = "Admin@123";

        var chkUser = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, userPWD);
```

ConfigureServices is follows.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {

            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                                                                   options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@/";
        })
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Default Password settings.
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
        });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

already added AllowedUserNameCharacters as "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@/"

But still return error 
 User name '' is invalid, can only contain letters or digits.

Comment: AllowedUserNameCharacters, according to Microsoft, defaults to: Gets or sets the list of allowed characters in the username used to validate user names. Defaults to abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+    For grins, comment out that line and try it with the default?  DOC if you want it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.useroptions.allowedusernamecharacters?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0):

You can turn this restriction off on the user validator:

```
UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<TUser>(UserManager) { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false }
```